# how to send multicast message to MUC and private message together

Tags: ejabberd

I use mod_multicast and I use 'to' attribute.

I try to send message to non-muc user (abc@example.com) and a muc user (mucuser@example.com)

If I set **`message type`** to **chat** then I get an error

```
it is not allowed to send private messages to conference.
```

If I set it to **groupchat**, then I get `service-unavailable` for non-muc (private) user.

How can I send multicast message to muc and non-muc (private) user in the same message?

```
<message to='multicast.header2.org' from='a@header1.org/work'>
   <addresses xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'>
      <address type='to'  jid='to@header1.org'/>
      <address type='to'  jid='cc@conference.header2.org'/>
   </addresses>
   <body>Hello, World!</body>
</message>
```